# Raphael.js custom element and new type?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I can use Raphael.js to custom my element,for example: arrow,but I can't change it's type,because the arrow actually is a path.the next code:

```
var ar = Raphael.arrow(...);
console.log(ar.type); //path
```

this will get "path",how can I change the type to "arrow",or others, even "diamod" or "obama"?

Edit:
here is the arrow function:

```
Raphael.fn.arrow = function  (x1,y1,x2,y2,wid,color) {
    color = color || 'blue';
    wid = wid || 3;
    return this.path('M'+x1+','+y1+'L'+x2+','+y2)
        .attr({'stroke':color,'stroke-width':wid,'arrow-end':'block-midium-midium'});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the method myself,it's sample but I go wrong way.let me just edit the function in my question:

```
Raphael.fn.arrow = function  (x1,y1,x2,y2,wid,color) {
    color = color || 'blue';
    wid = wid || 3;
    var ar = this.path('M'+x1+','+y1+'L'+x2+','+y2)
        .attr({'stroke':color,'stroke-width':wid,'arrow-end':'block-midium-midium'});
    ar.type = 'arrow';
    return ar;
}
```

then,when get the type it will be 'arrow'..

others type, just like so.